# It won't print full address

Tags: c++

Can somebody please tell me why it won't print my full address? The final output is "Your name is Syd and you live at 2845." Why is it doing this? I clearly state within the cout to print the address string. (by the way, I actually type 2845 SE Taylor Street)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string address;
    cout << "Please enter your address." << endl;
    cin >> address;
    cout << "You live at " << address << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cin >> address;
```

This reads a single word, stopping at the first white-space character. To read a whole line:

```
std::getline(cin, address);
```

Answer (score 2):

The input operator reads *space separated* values. So if your address have a space in it then it will read just the first "word.

And worse, if you enter your full name, the first input will read the first name, and the second input will read the second name.

Try to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the whole line, but first do `std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');` to skip the newline from the last input (or use `std::getline` for both inputs).

Comment: I did that. However, I don't know what to do next. Now do I use cout << address?

Comment: @Syd Yes. `std::getline` reads the whole line into the string (without the actual newline).

Comment: So, just to be clear, what would the full thing be? cout << "Your name is " << name << " and you live at " << std::getline << "." << endl;

Comment: The line from `std::getline` is stored in the second parameter of the function, so it should be: `string address; getline(cin, address); cout << "you live at" << address;`

Comment: @Syd I have link to a reference on `std::getline` in my answer. Follow it!